# htaccess redirect request jquery.js (Mailchimp on Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, .htaccess, mailchimp

I have problem with Mailchimp script embedded on Wordpress widget, when access each page on website got 404 error when load jquery.js, when i trace an URL like this :

- https://test.com/jquery.js
- https://test.com/category/jquery.js
- https://test.com/category/low/jquery.js
- https://test.com/about/jquery.js

Can i using .htaccess file to redirect all request to file **jquery.js** to **/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js**

Existing .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code in your functions.php and watch your web console, if first jquery.js 404 error dissapears, then add more redirections if you need it.

```
function jquery_mailchimp_redirect() {
    global $wp;
    $current_url = add_query_arg(  home_url( $wp->request ) );

    if( $current_url == '/jquery.js' ){
        wp_redirect( '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'jquery_mailchimp_redirect' );
```

It solved my problem in Flatsome theme, with "MailChimp for WooCommerce" oficial plugin. I hope it can solve yours.

Good luck! :)